# Create comma separated list from string but ignore commas within double quotes

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a list from a string delimited by commas, but there are a set of values within the string contained within quotes that also include commas. I want to create a list that ignores the commas within the quotes. I have a few hundred text documents in this format. This is (one of many of) the string:

```
str = ('1ATB,"300,2986,4151,3719,3488,3027,3123,3348,3530", ,2019-11-27 12:45:11.000,000-286428,Paint Powder,1ATB,')
```

The resulting list I am trying to get is:

```
['1ATB', '"300, 2986, 4151, 3719, 3488, 3027, 3123, 3348, 3530"', ' ', '2019-11-27 12:45:11.000', '000-286428', 'Paint Powder', '1ATB', '']
```

---

My first attempt of:

```
str=('1ATB,"300,2986,4151,3719,3488,3027,3123,3348,3530", ,2019-11-27 12:45:11.000,000-286428,Paint Powder,1ATB,')
list1 = str.split(",")
```

Yields the result of:

```
['1ATB', '"300', '2986', '4151', '3719', '3488', '3027', '3123', '3348', '3530"', ' ', '2019-11-27 12:45:11.000', '000-286428', 'Paint Powder', '1ATB', '']
```

I appreciate any advice for this.

Comment: Take a look at `shlex.split()` to honor quotes.

Comment: Have you heard of _regex_?

Comment: @Drdilyor, I actually would not consider this a good regular expression candidate. Not all languages are [regular languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language).

Comment: @Durren, ...also, this looks like you're trying to parse a CSV. Just use Python's built-in CSV parser.

Comment: I was trying out some CSV methods but wasn't getting a format that I wanted.  I'll look further into it though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps the [CSV module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) can help.

```py
>>> s = ('1ATB,"300,2986,4151,3719,3488,3027,3123,3348,3530", ,2019-11-27 12:45:11.000,000-286428,Paint Powder,1ATB,')
>>> print(s)
1ATB,"300,2986,4151,3719,3488,3027,3123,3348,3530", ,2019-11-27 12:45:11.000,000-286428,Paint Powder,1ATB,
>>> from io import StringIO
>>> import csv
>>> f = StringIO(s)
>>> reader = csv.reader(f)
>>> row = next(reader)
>>> row
['1ATB', '300,2986,4151,3719,3488,3027,3123,3348,3530', ' ', '2019-11-27 12:45:11.000', '000-286428', 'Paint Powder', '1ATB', '']
>>> row2 = [f'"{col}"' if ',' in col else col for col in row]
>>> row2
['1ATB', '"300,2986,4151,3719,3488,3027,3123,3348,3530"', ' ', '2019-11-27 12:45:11.000', '000-286428', 'Paint Powder', '1ATB', '']
>>>
```

Comment: This is very useful, thank you Justin. Is there a way I could preserve the double quotes in the end results with this method?

Comment: See edited answer.